# Documentation Proposed Changes Queue improvement

Tags: feature-request, documentation

There are a few problems with the proposed changes queue:

- New proposals arrive on top, which doesn't encourage users to deal with existing proposals first. Older ones gradually get further and further down the line, and might never be dealt with by anyone. If people are waiting for their edits to get reviewed, if older ones would be listed first, they would be encouraged to do some reviewing for the queue to shorten, but now you are not incited to do some work, rather to make more and more new propositions.
- I would think it useful if I could filter the list of proposed changes to see only changes I have not yet reviewed. This would encourage to deal with the proposal queue, since now I open many links just to see I already reviewed them.
- From ivarni: Navigate directly to next review item
- I also would like to add that I can't find a link to the actual topic. During or after review I would be able to click and go to the currently online topic, but all links seem to point to the 'proposed change'.

Comment: I agree, I was going to open the same request. I had to re-edit a couple of proposals 2-3 times because they went to the second page, and new small changes were approved first causing conflicts and issues.

Comment: Also, once a review is completed *take me to the next one*. Right now I have to navigate my browser back twice, then manually *pick* one from a list. This gets extremely cumbersome compared to the reviewer experience we have on main.

Comment: I find it hard to find the proposed changes queue at all! Imho it should be somewhere on the front page, and not i.e. `Java Language -> Arrays -> Dashboard -> Proposed Changes`. This feels hidden too much for such an important feature.

Comment: These problems are pretty bad, and are probably the reason there are so many pending changes. After I approve something I'm just stuck in a useless page, and it's difficult to return to the right place.

Comment: See also this question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328645/docs-so-needs-a-review-queue, some improvements seem to be planned.