# Next button after review task in documentation

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, documentation

Can the developers add a button to go to the next review task? Now I must return to the dashboard and select a new one. That is a long way to review a few review tasks.

[image]

Comment: related if not a dupe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328613/documentation-proposed-changes-queue-improvement

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328645/docs-so-needs-a-review-queue