# auto-advance feature for Documentation review queue?

Tags: feature-request, documentation

After approving a suggested edit in Documentation, the page updates to show that it's been approved, but I haven't found a convenient way to navigate to the next suggested edit (as occurs automatically in review queues); I have been hitting the Back button and finding the next suggestion in the queue manually. I guess this problem would be taken care of if [Docs.SO had its own dedicated review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328645/docs-so-needs-a-review-queue), but if that doesn't happen for some reason it would be nice to implement an easy "go to next suggestion" navigation option for this part of the Docs dashboard ...

Comment: i'm voting to close this: it's mentioned as one bullet point at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328613/documentation-proposed-changes-queue-improvement?rq=1